# Classes and Observable Object

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a data model class that can be referenced by different views. The data model has a function that can modify one of its published variables. However, this function is called inside one view, the change it makes to the published variable is not reflected in other views which also reference the class. The most simple example I can come up with is this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextView()
            ButtonView()
        }
    }
}

struct TextView: View {

    @ObservedObject var data = Data()

    var body: some View {
        Text(data.currentWord)
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {

    @ObservedObject var data = Data()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.data.randomWord()}) {
            Text("Random word")
        }
    }
}

class Data: ObservableObject {

    @Published var currentWord = "Cat"

    func randomWord() {
        let word = ["Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Horse"].randomElement()!
        print(word)
        currentWord = word

    }

}
```

Both the ButtonView and TextView reference the same class, and the ButtonView calls the 'Data' class's method 'randomWord' which modifies its 'currentWord' published variable. However, the change to this variable is not reflected in the Text of the TextView which also references the 'Data' class.

I think I'm not understanding something about classes and observableObject correctly. Would anyone be kind enough to point out my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create two different instance of Data in your subviews, instead you need to share one, so create it in `ContentView` and pass to subviews as below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data = Data()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextView(data: data)
            ButtonView(data: data)
        }
    }
}

struct TextView: View {

    @ObservedObject var data: Data

    var body: some View {
        Text(data.currentWord)
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {

    @ObservedObject var data: Data

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.data.randomWord()}) {
            Text("Random word")
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as variant, for such scenario can be used `EnvironmentObject` pattern. There are a lot of examples here on SO you can find about environment objects usage - just search by keywords.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that classes were reference types though, so can't multiple views reference the same class? Even if there are two instantiations of a class, my understanding was that they refer to the same class.

Comment: Saying `class` we mean `a type`, saying `instance` we mean `a unique object`. Human is a class, you and I are instances. So, yes, we refer to the same class, but you type in one TextView, and I, when type.... you see - here is your defect. =)

Comment: I kind of get it  . Thanks for your explanation. I'm not formally educated in CS so it's a big help.